# Cordova/Phonegap Build geolocation on iOS timeout

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I have been experiencing the same issue, and have tried in the past 2 weeks numerous solutions found online for this with no success, any help appreciated :)

I am writing a simple app using Cordova for IOS and Android and building it using Phonegap build. The problem is that I cannot get the "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" (or navigator.geolocation.watchPosition) calls to return anything except a timeout error on iOS. (works perfectly on Android)

***Additionally, the location services dialog never appears (requesting user permission to allow GPS for the app)***

To add to this strange behavior, it seems that i have to touch the screen after the app is loaded to initiate the geolocation call, on most cases the app just sits there and does nothing until the screen is touched.

Testing this on iPhone 5 with iOS 9

Things I tried:

1. Changing timeout settings (up to 30 seconds)
2. Setting enableHighAccuracy true/false
3. Running code with or without the geolocation plugin
4. Manually adding the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription/NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription settings (or both) to the plist file
5. Installing different plugin versions for the geolocation plugin
6. Changing Content Security Policy meta tag
7. Trying to add or remove the `<plugin>` declaration from root config.xml

**Current plugins installed ($cordova plugin list):**

```
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 2.3.5 "Diagnostic"
```

**Root config.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="info.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App name</name>
    <description>
        App Name
    </description>
    <author email="test@test.com" href="http://test.com">
        App Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

**index.js**

```js
var geo = {
    getGeo: function() {        
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              geo.onSuccess,
              geo.onError,
              {maximumAge:0, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: false});        

    },
    onSuccess: function(position) {
        alert('GOT location');

        alert(position.coords.latitude + ' --- ' + position.coords.longitude);
    },
    onError: function(error) {
        alert('error getting geo!');
    }   
};

 var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        geo.getGeo();
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**iOS Plist file:**

```xml
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
```

**Index.html:**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help in the right direction appreciated!

Comment: Your code looks correct, and actually better than most I see. However, the only thing left that I can see is you are sitting in GPS dead zone. Here is a [tutorial on GPS and map production](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki). Make sure to read **GPS is Unreliable** For the record, when getting GPS readings, with the plugin, you do NOT get dialog requests from the system. Also, I have working examples I can give you, the work for each of the "core" plugins.

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650 I checked your article which is indeed quite helpful. However I have never seen the app getting even an inaccurate lat/lon from the code i posted. I doubt that i'm sitting in a GPS dead zone, as I tried it in several locations, all returning the same timeout error on iOS (as i mentioned this works without a problem on an old Android device I have on hand).

Comment: you are right. my mistake. I deleted my answer. I'll be back to this later today.

Comment: I have to run an errand. I won't be back to this for sometime. If you want here is a link to the [Cordova Bug Repository for Geolocation Plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4798?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20Geolocation%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20summary%20ASC%2C%20updatedDate%20DESC). There are 24 outstanding issues, 12 are related to iOS.

Comment: [This one looks related](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8341?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20Geolocation%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22ios%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20summary%20ASC%2C%20updatedDate%20DESC). FWIW, I looked at [my demo code](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-GPS-Test). I just used `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()`

Comment: Are you using an SDK/IDE like Android Studio, Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.? Is the code for this app in a public respository? What is your target platform? FWIW, I'm looking at your code - right now.

Comment: I'm looking at your code. I see where it came from. It is the "Cordova Hello World". I'm looking at more details. Please respond to the last question. TIA

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650, I did not install any IDE, i do have visual studio but not using it for this project. I installed cordova, and created a new project, with ios and android platforms added. I then added the geolocation code and plugin. not building the project locally, using PhoneGap Build to compile and install it on my devices. I did try to use the navigator.geolocation.watchposition instead, but getting same timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@daddio
Oh. that's it. I should be more dogmatic on this. This should take care of the problem.

It is not advisable to use *Phonegap CLI* to make your *Phonegap Build* build project. Phonegap build requires that `index.html` and `config.xml` both sit in the root directory. All the extra files that you are required to use with *Phonegap CLI*, never are created or needed with *Phonegap Build*.

So, I'm going to give you one of my working demos. Notice that all the files are in one (1) directory.

- tutorial/blog entry - [An HTML Boilerplate for *Phonegap Build*](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html)
- source code [Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate)

Notice how the compiler version is set to:

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />`

Notice, if you change `cli-5.2.0` to `3.7.0`, nothing appears to change.

Basically for *Phonegap Build*, you need `index.html` and `config.xml` - that's it. Then for security reasons (as of *Cordova Tools* 5.0.0), it is advisable to create a `css` file and a `javascript` file. However, I'll show you  how to get around this.

Here is my complete list of Demo Apps.

- [Phonegap Demo Apps](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/)

### YOUR FIX

This is my working code, test with  3.5.0 and cli-5.1.1 and cli5.2.0

- source code [Phonegap-GPS-Test](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-GPS-Test)

*On Your fix*, notice how the version is set to:  `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />`

Okay, I trust all of this will work for you. As such, your documentation is here:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs

There are some special rules for adding plugins, but I'll give you those when your program is running.

### How to add Plugins with *Phonegap Build*

1. FOR THE MOST IMMEDIATE FUTURE, get your *core* plugins from this list:
   http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html
2. Get your 3rd-party plugin from this source:
   http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/
3. When using *Phonegap Build*, sometimes the pluins get fixed (or updated) and this breaks *Phonegap Build*. This is because the "fixes" require the latest version of the compiler, and *Phonegap Build* is always at least one version behind.

There are two ways to deal with 3; see 4 and 5.

4. I have created [this Worksheet](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md). You may want to make a copy or just use it as a reference. I use this worksheet to create my demos, I so know the list is good. I am working on cli-5.2.0 right now. (Should finish by Monday or so.) However, I do not test ALL 3rd-party plugins; there are 800+ plugins.
5. If you fail to set the version number on a plugin, you will get the latest version. If your build fails, then set the version. If the build still fails, try the previous two or three version to find one that works. NOTE, these older plugins may have bugs that prevent you from using them. So, try an even earlier version.

Lastly, if you think you have hit a bug, then here is [a page with links to the Bug respository for each plugin](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-bugs.md). Last Update is on the top left. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650, your examples worked :) it will be nice indeed if you can provide the rules for adding plugins. Cheers!